# Always have enough resources for IIS asp.net site

Tags: iis, windows-service

I have an internet facing IIS asp.net site which is an ERP medical site built where users login, search for patients,  download/upload documents, review bills, etc....

On the same VM (2012 r2, vsphere essentials 6.0) I built a windows service that runs several tasks such as sending thousands of faxes, emails and SMS to patients, doctors and attorneys.

When the service runs it impacts the site to where its unusable while the service runs.

We try and run most after hours but some have to get performed during the day.

Is there a way to always save X amount of resources for the site or what would be the best practice for this scenario?  Break the service off to a new VM?

I am trying to avoid just adding more resources as the windows service to run is not a priority.

Comment: `Break the service off to a new VM`? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time there was a tool call WSRM (windows server resource manager).  This was deprecated then removed.  The solution you want is to separate out the service on to another instance using either Hyper-V or VMware and dedicating resources to each VM.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to have another window install to manage.  If I upgrade to 2016 and add the IIS as a container can I dedicate resources to the container on the same VM?